# Smoke causes FPS to drop to almost unplayable levels

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2, technical-issues

While everything else runs very smoothly, any kind of smoke (from smoke grenades, mortar, tank guns, collapsing buildings) slows graphics down to single digit FPS. The effect is proportional to the relative area of screen covered by smoke.

I've tried turning down every graphics setting there is (both in-game and driver) to no avail. Is this a common problem (or even a "feature" of BC2) or is there a way to fix it?

*Relevant specs: i5-760 2.8GHz, 8GB RAM, ATI HD 5770 1GB.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good idea to look into the Catalyst Control Centre for graphical settings. You can use the CCC to override (or even compound) graphical settings for games, and this may be the case for you. You should try finding the settings for anti aliasing, anisotropic filtering and texture quality settings (to start). Try turning those down, and they should directly help you out.

Failing that try uninstalling your graphics card drivers, rebooting, then installing new graphics card drivers from amd.com .

What it sounds like is that your graphics card is applying texture improvement processes to the smoke textures, processes such as anisotropic filtering, and it's simply set way too high.